# Netlify rewrite country path

Tags: redirect, routes, url-rewriting, netlify

I am trying to set up rewrites in Netlify.
I have generated directories for each countries, so I can access `mydomain.com/fra`
Now i want to hiding country path to `mydomain.com`, but accessing `mydomain.com/fra`

Can I do that in Netlify?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this -> https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#redirect-by-country-or-language

`netlify.toml` example

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/fra/:splat"
status = 200
force = true
conditions = {Country = "fra"}
```